# A subset if weakly bounded if and only if its polar is absorbing

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces, weak-topology

Let $X$ be a locally convex space and $A\subseteq X$. The polar of $A$ is a subset $A^\circ$ of the dual $X^\ast$ defined by $A^\circ\equiv \{x^\ast\in X^\ast:|\langle a,x^\ast\rangle|\leq 1,\, \forall a\in A\}$.

Now an exercise in Conway's book on functional analysis states that a subset $A$ is bounded (in the sense of a topological vector space) in the weak topology if and only if $A^\circ$ is absorbing.

**Now I wonder how to prove this and also if this is even true?**

My skepticism  comes from the fact that if $x^\ast\in A^\circ$ satisfies $|\langle a,x^\ast\rangle| = 1$ for some $a\in A$ then by mutliplying with a unimodular constant we can assume that $\langle a,x^\ast\rangle = 1$. However then $A^\circ$ is not absorbing at $x^\ast$ since there is no $r>0$ such that $x^\ast+rx^\ast\in A^\circ$. (In that case $\langle a,x^\ast+rx^\ast\rangle = 1+r>1$!)

So if I'm correct this implies that $|\langle a,x^\ast\rangle|<1$ for every $a\in A$ and $x^\ast\in A^\circ$ in the event that $A$ is bounded? But this surely fails for normed spaces: If $X$ is normed and $B$ is the closed unit ball in $X$ then $B^\circ$ would be the closed unit ball in $X^\ast$. If $\|x\| = 1$ for some $x\in X$ then by Hahn-Banach we can find a continuous linear functional $x^\ast$ with norm $1$ such that $\langle x,x^\ast\rangle = 1$.

Comment: When you write LCS, do you mean locally convex?

Comment: yes this is what I mean

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the definition of an absorbing set. $S$ is absorbing if for every $y$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $\lambda y \in S$ for all scalars $\lambda$ with $\lvert\lambda\rvert \leqslant \delta$. That $A^{\circ}$ is absorbing therefore means that for every $x^{\ast}$ the set $\{ x^{\ast}(a) : a \in A\}$ is bounded.

Comment: Ah I see my mistake. I understood it as what Conway calls "absorbing at each point".